# How can I restrict the user to upload a certain amount of data in Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want my user to **add/upload only 3 nodes per child**. Is there a way I can **restrict using these rules?**
I'm working with Flutter and using **Firebase Real-time database**.

Here is Image of my database. I want my user to able to **add just 3 contacts** only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
alert
    userContacts
        1234567890
            contact1
                name: 'Adbul Twelves'
                phone: 1212121212
            contact2
                name: 'Abdullah Elevens'
                phone: 1111111111
            contact3
                name: 'Ahmed Tens'
                phone: 1010101010
```

and make rules to allow only these 3 keys. Then, in the client, when adding a new contact, you'd first need to read how many contacts your already have.

You can use `1, 2, 3` instead of `contact1, contact2, contact3` if you prefer working with arrays in your code.